# Equal quotient groups

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group, $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ and $K$. Suppose also that $H/N = K/N$. Does this mean that $H = K$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean $H/N\cong K/N$, then no - consider the example of 
$$G=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}), \quad H=\{(0,0),(1,0)\},\quad K=\{(0,0),(0,1)\},\quad N=\{(0,0)\}$$
then $$H/N\cong H\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cong K\cong K/N,$$ but $H\neq K$.

If you really literally mean $H/N=K/N$, as an equality of underlying sets, then yes: the inverse image of $H/N=K/N$ under the quotient homomorphism $q:G\to G/N$ will necessary be equal to both $H$ and $K$, [by the fourth isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_theorem), hence $H=K$.